# MeteorJS basic jquery usage

Tags: jquery, node.js, meteor

In a clean meteor application with the added jquery package, I'm attempting to use the basic jquery css selector. What Am I doing wrong? The non-working example can be found here: http://jquery-test.meteor.com/

The JavaScript is placed directly below the generated `template.hello.events` method.

JS:

```
$("#foo").click( function() {
console.log("clicked!");
});
```

HTML:

```
<button id="foo" style="border: 10px">This is a test div</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to place the jQuery code inside the `Template.hello.rendered` function.

Comment: So, for clarity: Meteor dynamically generates html elements. This means that I need to place my jQuery code in a place that ensures the element has already been rendered?

Comment: Yep, on startup, Meteor aggregates all the <template>, <head>, and <body> tags throughout the .html files in your whole app, and then renders the Templates dynamically, wrapping all the DOM elements in its spark engine for reactive updating.

Answer (score 1):

This could be another approach to your problem:

**HTML:**

```
<button id="foo" class="foo" style="border: 10px">This is a test div</button>
```

**JS:**

```
Template.hello.events({
 'click .foo': function(event){
    console.log('clicked');
    console.log(event.currentTarget);  
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned and i saw the link, Your `elems are dynamically generated` and you are trying to put event on those which are not available in the dom. So you have to delegate the event to the `existing closest parent` or `document` which is the `existing parent` of all other elems.

You can bind the event like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#foo', function() {
    console.log("clicked!");
});
```

and `make sure to load jQuery first.`